# Trying to display User info from a database in my Android application

Tags: java, php, android, session, sharedpreferences

I have been working on this for a while. The first thing I have tried is storing the logged in user in a session, and then trying to use that variable later such as the following:

**Login.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

$sessionid = session_id();

    require_once('connect.inc.php');

    $sql = "SELECT username, password FROM USER WHERE username = ?";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);

    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->bind_result($user, $pass);

    while($stmt->fetch()){
        $verify = password_verify($password, $pass);
    }

    if($verify){
        $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
        echo 'connected';
    echo $sessionid;
    }else{
        echo 'check details';
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```

I am then taking the response of the login in message and splitting it into two variables. The login response and session id. I take the session id and store in shared preferences. I am trying to store the session ID in my java method so I can access the session user. Here is my java code for attempting to get the user:

**GetUserData Java method**

```
private void getUserData() {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Config.sharedPref, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String sessionId = sharedPreferences.getString(Config.SID, "SessionID");

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, Config.SERVER_ADDRESS + "GetUserData.php?PHPSESSID=" + sessionId,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                    try {
                        //json string to jsonobject
                        jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                        //get json sstring created in php and store to JSON Array
                        result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.json_array);

                        //get username from json array
                        getUserInfo(result);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void getUserInfo(JSONArray jsonArray){
    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        try {
            JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            userInfo.add(json.getString(Config.getUsername));
        } catch (JSONException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the php file the java method is attempting to call:

**GetUserData.php**

```
<?php
 session_start();
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET'){

            $username = $_SESSION['username'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM USER WHERE username = '$username'";

    require_once('connect.inc.php');

    $run = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $result = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run)){
        array_push($result, array(
            'id' => $row['id'],
            'fname' => $row['fname'],
            'lname' => $row['lname'],
            'username' => $row['username'],
            'email' => $row['email'],
        ));
    }

    echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));

    mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```

When debugging, the 'result' array is empty, so for some reason,

```
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM USER WHERE username = '$username'";
```

is not working. I know it has something to do with sessions, but Im not sure where the problem is.

My next attempt is going to try to just store the logged in user in shared preferences, and then call that variable from a php file and run a query to display user info with that variable. How would I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What you will do is to send a request when a user enters username and password to the server as you have done here. Note I modified your code.

String enteredUsername = "username";
String enteredPassword = "xxxxxx";

```
String uri = String.format("http://somesite.com/some_endpoint.php?param1=%1$s&param2=%2$s", enteredUsername, enteredPassword);

 StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, uri,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                try {
                    // parse the response object and store user id and data in sharedpreference.
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });

RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Check the user has not been registered, add the user to your database and return the user database unique id plus other data you want.

then save the user id and username to SharedPreference

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Config.sharedPref, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
sharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
edit.putStringSet("Personal Information", set);
edit.commit();
```

You should first check if a user id is stored in preference to determine if the user is a registered user. if the user is not register show the login form else redirect user to profile activity page.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I added some more information including my login method.

Answer (score 0):

I already have a login class that makes sure the user is registered. I'm just trying to get the user information from the database as I have stated. Here is the login method as I probably should have provided it:

```
private void login(){
        final String username = txtUsrnm.getText().toString().trim();
        final String password = txtPswrd.getText().toString().trim();

        //create string request
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.SERVER_ADDRESS + "Login.php",
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        String responseOne = response.substring(0,9);
                        String responseTwo = response.substring(9);
                        if(responseOne.equalsIgnoreCase(Config.logInMessage)){
                            //create shared pref
                            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = Login.this.getSharedPreferences(Config.sharedPref, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                            //editor stores values to the shared pref
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                            //add values
                            editor.putBoolean(Config.sharedPrefBool, true);
                            editor.putString(Config.username, username);
                            editor.putString(Config.password, password);
                            editor.putString(Config.SID, responseTwo);
                            editor.commit();

                            Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Home.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }else{
                            //display error message
                            Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Wrong Username or Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                //from android.com: A Map is a data structure consisting of a set of keys and
                // values in which each key is mapped to a single value. The class of the objects
                // used as keys is declared when the Map is declared, as is the class of the
                // corresponding values.
                Map<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

                //maps specified string key, username and password, to specified string value
                hashMap.put(Config.username, username);
                hashMap.put(Config.password, password);

                return hashMap;
            }
        };

        //add string request to queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```